# Paginating content in an Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, pagination

I am developing an epub reader. I was able to finally display correctly the content. However, I noticed that there is no pagination in an epub. All content are displayed as 1 scrollable page. What I want to achieve is that there should be no scrollable content at the bottom. Those contents should be on the next page, something like that.

Is there a way to make the content paginate using javascript? I'm not familiar with javascript so I'm not sure how I do it. I've read somewhere that i can achieve it through column?

Comment: hey.. i am facing same problem if you found any  way please share..